# Show table with fetched json data on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to fetch the json data fetched from a web service. I've fetched data successfully but I want to show it in a table form only after a button click. 
The following code shows the name of table rows when the page is load.It should only appear after a button click.

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var request = null;

            function createRequest()
            {
                try {
                    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch (trymicrosoft)
                {
                    try {
                        request = new ActiveXObject("MsXML2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (othermicrosoft)
                    {
                        try {
                            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch (failed) {
                            request = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (request == null)
                    alert("Error creating request object!");
            }

            function getMessage(lat,lon)
            {
                 alert(lat);
                createRequest();
                ;
                    var dis = document.getElementById("dt_id").value;
                var url = "http://localhost:8080/testrestfullapi/webresources/drugController/getdata/"+dis;
                 alert(url);
                
                request.open("GET", url, true);

request.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;

                request.send(null);

            }

            function handleResponse()
            {
                                if (request.readyState == 4){
                                 alert("readystate=4");
                                  var check=request.status;
                       alert(check);
                        alert(request.responseText);
           if(check.toString()=="200")
                  alert("status ok");         
                    var det = eval("(" + request.responseText + ")");
                     alert(det);
                    var data = "";
                    var i = 0;
                    for (var property in det) {
                                  alert("Entered in for loop");
                        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(det, property)) {
                            data = data + "<tr>";
                            data = data + "<td class=\"sorting_1\">" + det[i].disease + "</td>";
                            data = data + "<td class=\" sorting_1\">" + det[i].drug + "</td>";
                            data = data + "<td class=\" sorting_1\">" + det[i].trade + "</td>";
                            i++;
                        }

                    }
                    document.getElementById("table_data").innerHTML = data;
                }
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:left; margin:8px 5px auto;">
        <label for="dt_id">Please enter disease </label>
        <input type="Text" id="dt_id" maxlength="25" size="25"/>
        <input type='button' onclick='getMessage()' value='SUBMIT'> 
</div>
 
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th>Disease</th>
                    <th>Drug</th>
                    <th>Trade</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table_data">

            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to hide the `table` initially. Hide the table by using this attribute `style="display:none;"` .. Then in button click you can show the table when you want...

Comment: I'm new at html and javascript. The style attribute hides the table but how to display it back on a button click that i don't know. Thank you for your quick and useful reply.

Comment: Set a ID attribute to your table like `id="MyTable"` and you can do `$("#MyTable").show()` to show the table.. This is a Jquery syntax.. Since you have added Jquery tag in the question

Comment: I tried for jquery but that didn't work. Don't know what was the reason there. But then I put table into <div> tag and set style.display property to none. And in function I set back it to 'block' and that worked. But same thing doesn't worked with table itself. Any idea?   Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is you wouldn't have added Jquery library reference in your page. Also as you said it worked for div.. The same syntax will work for table too, just change the ID selector to table id

Comment: Done!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: If this answer helped you resolve your issue then please mark it as answer